# SQL query to fetch records within a time range for particular date range/period

Tags: sql, oracle

Looking for a SQL query to fetch TABLE records within a time range for a particular date period.

For example, 
How to write query, if I need to fetch records from a table `TABLE1` where

`DATE_COLUMN >= 2019-04-01 AND DATE_COLUMN < 2019-04-10`

and also Time of these selected records should be within `12:00` to `13:00`

*Note : Datatype of `TABLE1.DATE_COLUMN` is `DATE` which also holds time part*

Please help

Comment: Did you try anything? Did any research about it? Googled it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd try with something like this:

```
select *
from your_Table
where date_column >= date '2019-04-01'
  and date_column <  date '2019-04-10'
  and to_number(to_char(date_column, 'hh24miss')) between 120000 and 130000;
```

Comment: Possible small problem - since you are converting the time to 'hh24', this will return anything where the time portion is between 12:00 and 13:59:59.  Depending on how precise the OP wants to be, you might just use `to_char(date_column, 'hh24')) = 12`.  In any case, this is the right idea.

Comment: So true, @Dave. Thank you, fixed!

Comment: Dear friend, this does not work for hour `13:00:00` yet.

Comment: Hello, @Barbaros! Makes sense, as the OP stated "between 12 and 13", and 13:00 fits into that. I modified it to take care about time up to seconds; hopefully, it'll be OK. Thank you too!

Comment: Thanks @Littlefoot, this is what I was looking for... :)

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using `trunc()` function due to your needs for hour interval

```
with t(date_column) as
(
 select timestamp'2019-04-01 13:00:00' from dual union all
 select timestamp'2019-04-02 13:00:01' from dual union all
 select timestamp'2019-04-08 12:55:00' from dual    
)
select *  
  from t
  where ( to_char(date_column,'hh24') = '12'
     or ( to_char(date_column,'hh24') = '13' and trunc(date_column,'hh24') = date_column ) )
    and trunc(date_column) between date'2019-04-01' and date'2019-04-09';

DATE_COLUMN
-------------------
01.04.2019 13:00:00
08.04.2019 12:55:00
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/DLMM62108)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

use condition like below

```
where DATE_COLUMN >= '2019-04-01 12:00:00' AND DATE_COLUMN < '2019-04-10 13:00:00'
```

Comment: I think they want to apply the time filter (between 12:00 and 13:00) to each day's records.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from TableName
where 
convert(date,ColumnName) >= convert(date,'2019-04-01') and 
convert(date,ColumnName) <  convert(date,'2019-04-10') and
substring(CONVERT(VARCHAR, ColumnName, 108),0,6) between '16:54' and '17:56';
```